# Codeigniter - url segment replace or redirect

Tags: codeigniter, url, redirect

I have a base controller (`base`) which all other controllers extend from.
Anything placed here will override other controllers, the redirects will be here.

**URLs example:**

```
 http://domain.com/controllerone/function
 http://domain.com/controllertwo/function
 http://domain.com/controllerthree/function
```

Using the code below. will give me the controller name

```
$this->uri->segment(1);
```

Each of the above controllers need to be redirected to separate URLs, but the funcation part should not change:

```
 http://domain.com/newcontrollerone/function
 http://domain.com/newcontrollertwo/function
 http://domain.com/newcontrollerthree/function
```

In my base controller i want the following logic:

```
    $controller_name =   $this->uri->segment(1);

    if($controller_name === 'controllerone'){
       // replace the controller name with new one and redirect, how ?
    }else if($controller_name === 'controllertwo'){
     // replace the controller name with new one and redirect, how ?
    }else{
        // continue as normal
   }
```

i was thinking i should use `redirect()` function and `str_replace()`, but dont know  how efficient these would be. Ideally i do not want to use the `Routing` class.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CodeIgniter's URI Routing](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html), should be able to help in this case. However, if you have a good reason not to use it, then this solution may help.

The potential redirects are in an array, where the *key* is the controller name being looked for in the URL and the *value* is the name of the controller to redirect to. This may not be the most efficient but I think it should be easier to manage and read than a potentially very long `if-then-else` statement.

```
//Get the controller name from the URL
$controller_name = $this->uri->segment(1);
//Alternative: $controller_name = $this->router->fetch_class();

//List of redirects
$redirects = array(
    "controllerone" => "newcontrollerone",
    "controllertwo" => "newcontrollertwo",
    //...add more redirects here
);

//If a redirect exists for the controller    
if (array_key_exists($controller_name, $redirects))
{
    //Controller to redirect to
    $redirect_controller = $redirects[$controller_name];
    //Create string to pass to redirect
    $redirect_segments = '/'
                       . $redirect_controller
                       . substr($this->uri->uri_string(), strlen($controller_name)); //Function, parameters etc. to append (removes the original controller name)
    redirect($redirect_segments, 'refresh');    
}
else
{
    //Do what you want...
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, should this be `redirect($redirect_url, 'refresh');` >> `redirect($redirect_segments, 'refresh');` ?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
header("Location:".base_url("newcontroller/".$this->uri->segment(2)));
```

Comment: I think `redirect('newcontroller/'.$this->uri->segment(2));` would be more idiomatic with CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 1):

Simple Solution using segment_array:

```
$segs = $this->uri->segment_array();

if($segs[1] === 'controllerone'){
  $segs[1] = "newcontroller";
   redirect($segs);
}else if($segs[1] === 'controllertwo'){
   $segs[1] = "newcontroller2";
   redirect($segs);
}else{
    // continue as normal
}
```